# advanced hover button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation, css3pie

I have no idea how to do this effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a simple example about how to do it

```
<style>

    p{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 136px;
    }

    .circle{
        position: absolute;
        height: 5px;
        width: 5px;
        background: #00ff00;
        right: -20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        top: 5px;
        transition: ease-in-out .2s all;
        z-index: -1;
    }
   

    .line{
        position: absolute;
        height: 2px;
        width: 40px;
        background: #00ff00;
        right: -70px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        top: 5px;
        transition: ease-in-out .2s all;
    }
    p:hover .circle{
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        background: red;
        right: -30px;
        border-radius: 38px;
        margin: auto;
        top: -20px;
    }
    p:hover .line{
        width: 60px;
        right: -90px;
    }
    p:hover .white-on-hover{
        color: #fff;
        transition: ease-in-out .2s all;
    }

    
</style>

<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        //get cms string
        var cmsText = document.getElementById('cmsText').innerHTML;

        //separe words
        cmsText = cmsText.split(' ');

        //get last words
        lastWord = cmsText[cmsText.length-1];

        //separe letters
        lastWord = lastWord.split('');
        var newLastWord = '';

        //concat all letters and add span with class "white-on-hover" before last 4 letters
        for(let i = 0; i < lastWord.length; i++){
            if(i == lastWord.length-4){
                newLastWord+='<span class="white-on-hover">';
                newLastWord += lastWord[i];
            }else if(i == lastWord.length-1){
                newLastWord += lastWord[i];
                newLastWord+='</span>';
            }else{
                newLastWord += lastWord[i];
            }
        }

        //concat all words adding the new last word
        var newCmsText = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < cmsText.length; i++){
            if(i != cmsText.length-1){
                newCmsText += cmsText[i];
                newCmsText += ' ';
            }else{
                newCmsText += newLastWord;
            }
            
        }

        //change the text for new text
        document.getElementById('cmsText').innerHTML = newCmsText;
        
    }
    
</script>



<p><span id="cmsText">title button advanced</span> <span class="circle"></span>  <span class="line"></span> </p>
```

Note 1: I'm using a lot of html tags span, this is not a good HTML syntax. This is an example and is a good pratice if you change some details

Note 2: This JavaScript isn't the best solution, it works and is very simple to understand

Comment: Hi very good!!

but i am printing random titles that are loaded via cms, i would need to get the last 4 letters of each title, any ideas? and these last ones make them the hover effect

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Front-Developer1989 I've updated the answer adding js code. This code get the text and change what you need.

Comment: Hello, print the variable and with the first variable it works but when printing more variables it doesn't work, only the first one works